# Pupils - Correlation between exam mark and answer from 1 to 5 of a test

Tags: r, self-study, correlation, mathematical-statistics, pearson-r

100 pupils have their exam mark from 1 t0 50 and separately they have reposed a questionary with 10 questions. The variable that represents the answers for the questions of the questionary are normalised answers that can be 1,1,25,1.50, 1.75 and 2 and it is called "**score**'.

Data set is 50 pupils X 10 questions = 500 rows where the variable Exam mark will be aways the same for each student.

I have tried:

```
cor.test(my_data$score,my_data$Exam_mark)
```

Doubts:
Can I consider  the variable 'score'as numerical so the above code would be right?

UPDATED

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) (you'll have to remove a tag). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: What is it you are supposed to be correlating & why?

Comment: Thanks @gung . Updated!